# Entity Framework issues when I need to have multiple relations of the same type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

This issue has been dogging me for a while, and would appreciate any help

Let's say I have two classes, users and room, that basically go like this

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Room> Rooms {get; set;}
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int RoomId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Owner")] // have tried with and without the explicit relationship
    public int OwnerId {get; set;}
    public User Owner {get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Members {get; set;}
}
```

My hope is to build s structure that allows a user to have multiple rooms where they are the owner, but also be included into multiple rooms as a member.

The problem comes when I actually try to make a room and add the members. The owner properties are added, but the Members list is always empty.

I'm using the annotation API, but have also tried the fluent API

When I try this, I get a multiplicity error

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Members).WithMany(u => u.Rooms);
```

I am sure the answer is simple, I am just not that good with entity. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the code you gave us your `.HasMany(t => t.Users)` has a different property name than the `Members` on your `Room` class.

Comment: @krillgar, yes sorry, I renamed a few fields form my actual code to attempt to make my intent clearer, I missed that one though.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two relationships between `User` and `Room`:

- Rooms where user is the owner (`one-to-many`)
- Rooms where user is a member (`many-to-many`)

Single `Rooms` collection cannot represent the two relationships, you need two collections:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Room> OwnerOfRooms {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Room> MemberOfRooms {get; set;}
}
```

and use the following Fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.OwnerOfRooms)
    .WithRequired(r => r.Owner)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.OwnerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.MemberOfRooms)
    .WithMany(r => r.Members);
```

Note that the second relationship will create automatic junction table `UserRooms`.

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I am still getting the multiplicity error when I try it

Comment: Added .WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to first function, works beautifully (I think)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF Core, to create a Many-to-Many, which is what you're after, you'll need to have another entity, `UserRoom`, which contains a 1-to-Many with `Users` and  1-to-Many with `Room`, like:

```
public class UserRoom
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }    
}
```

Then in `User`:

```
    [InverseProperty(nameof(UserRoom.User))]
    public ICollection<UserRoom> UserRooms { get; set; }
```

and similarly in `Room`:

```
    [InverseProperty(nameof(UserRoom.Room))]
    public ICollection<UserRoom> UserRooms { get; set; }
```

In your case, it sounds like you want two many-to-many relationships - one for room membership and one for room ownership.  In that case, you'll need to implement this pattern twice, with linking entities perhaps more appropriately named OwnerRoom and MemberRoom.

If room ownership is unique to a single user, then you'll need MemberRoom and the pattern above along with a standard 1-to-many relationship with Room and User, like you've already implemented, just decorate `User.Rooms` with:

`[InverseProperty(nameof(Room.Owner))]`